# Maximum number of integers $(m,n)$ in $A\times B$ such that $|m-n|\leq 1000$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set contains $2000$ distinct integers and $B$ be a set contains $2016$ distinct integers.

$K$ is the numbers of pairs $(m,n)$ satisfying  \begin{cases} m\in A, n\in B\\ |m-n|\leq 1000 \end{cases}  Find the maximum value of $K$

Axel Kemper's wise idea simplified this problem.

From his answer, I'll calculate the value of $K$ by hand.

$K$ = number of lattice points $(m,n)$ in the intersection area

Intersection area = area of rectangle - area of two triangles at left upper and right lower corner

Since lines n=m+1000 and n=m-1000 are parallel to line n=m, so the two triangles are right isoceles triangles which there are 1007 points on triangle leg (from -1 to -1007 for left upper triangle).

Number of lattice points in rectangular area = $2000\cdot2016$.

Number of lattice points in two right isoceles triangles = $2\cdot (1007+1006+...+1) = 1007\cdot1008$

$K = 2000\cdot2016 - 1007\cdot1008 = 3,016,944$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the constraint $|m-n|\leq 1000$, the potential $(m, n)$ pairs would form a rectangular area of points in a 2D $(m, n)$ diagram. You can stretch the rectangle by introducing gaps in the values in $A$ and $B$. The most compact form of the rectangle with a maximum of pair points per area would result if the integer sets $A$ and $B$ do not have any gaps.

Constraint $|m-n|\leq 1000$ can be represented by the area delimited by two parallel lines $n = m + 1000$ and $n = m - 1000$.

The intersection between the above described gap-less rectangle and the inequality area is maximized if the center of the rectangle is located along the middle line $n = m$. Therefore, we can assume $n = m = 0.5$ as center. This results in $A = \{-999, -998, ... 999, 1000\}$ and $B = \{-1007, -1006, ... 1007, 1008\}$.

It should now be not too difficult to calculate the number of pairs in the intersection area. Iterate $m$ from minimum to maximum and sum up the number of allowed values for $n$, depending on $m$.

My computer tells me: $K = 3016944$

Comment: Thank you, Axel. Does gap-less mean "consecutive integers" ?

Comment: @carat Yes, consecutive is the correct term.